# How to know the dependency of a library ? How to manually upgrade a library to a new version?

Tags: android, android-library

I m not under android studio, and I need to upgrade manually these libraries :

```
play-services-location-10.2.1.aar
play-services-tasks-10.2.1.aar
play-services-base-10.2.1.aar
play-services-appinvite-10.2.1.aar
play-services-basement-10.2.1.aar
firebase-analytics-10.2.1.aar
firebase-analytics-impl-10.2.1.aar
firebase-common-10.2.1.aar
firebase-crash-10.2.1.aar
firebase-iid-10.2.1.aar
firebase-messaging-10.2.1.aar
```

to their equivalent in version 12.0.1. But how to know/list the dependencies of each of theses new libraries (maybe it's will be not the same as before) ? what else i must be aware when i update the libraries ?

Comment: If not Android studio, in which IDE are you doing Android development?

Comment: Or, Android Studio is just an IDE. How do you build your project?

Comment: @nimi0112: on delphi ...

Comment: @EugenPechanec: I use Delphi, i build native ARM code

Comment: are you using gradle for build?

Comment: @Sagar: no i can't :(